# Converting Æ to "Ae" In PHP With Str_replace?

Tags: php, utf-8

For reasons justified by business logic, I need to convert the character "Æ" to "Ae" in a string.  However, despite the fact that mb_detect_encoding() tells me the string is UTF-8, I can't figure out how to do this.  (And for other reasons of business logic, it would be an issue to htmlentities() the string before replacing it, as other Google searches have suggested.)

What I tried first was this, using the test string "Æther":

```
return str_replace("Æ", 'Ae', $string);
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't actually find the Æ in the text, returning "Æther".

```
return str_replace(chr(195), 'Ae', $string);
```

That finds the Æ and replaces it, but adds an unknown character afterwards, changing it to the not-usable "Ae�ther."  So I tried this:

```
$ae_character = mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval(195) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
return str_replace($ae_character, 'Ae', $string);
```

Which again failed to find the Æ character in the string.  I know it's a UTF-8 issue of some sort, but I'm honestly stumped as to how to search for and replace this without adding the extra character afterwards.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need mb_string functionality. Afaik, PHP is not UTF8 ready.

Comment: Are you sure your `$string` is UTF-8? Maybe it’s a different encoding and `mb_detect_encoding` is giving the wrong result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$x = 'Æmystr';
print str_replace('Æ', 'AE', $x); // prints: AEmystr
?>
```

That code works just fine, what I believe you're missing is changing the encoding of your file. Your .php file should be encoded in UTF-8 or UNICODE. This can be done in some (text) editors or IDEs, i.e Eclipse, EditPlus, Notepad++ etc... Even Notepad on windows 7.

When saving bring up the Save/Save As dialog, and normally near the Save button there is an Encoding dropdown/radio buttons, that lets you choose between ANSI and UTF-8 (and others).

On *nix I believe most editors have it, just not sure of the locations. If after you do it and get it working, then edit/save with an editor that just does ANSI it'll overwrite it with an unknown char etc...

As to why the below code didn't work.

```
return str_replace(chr(195), 'Ae', $string);
```

It's because a unicode char is normally 2 chars put together. So what you have above is just the start of the unicode char. try this:

```
print str_replace(chr(195).chr(134), 'AE', $x);
```

That should replace it as well and might even be preferred as you (might|do) not have to change the file encoding.

Comment: Excellent - the adding the chr(134) afterwards did work, without me having to worry about encoding my editor!  Now a follow-up question, if it's not too much trouble: Would every chr() in UTF-8 also be followed by a chr(134), or is that just local to Ae?  If not, then do you know where I'd find a list?

Answer (score 0):

[Click on this for a link to characters page](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/latin-diphthong-ae-uppercase-ascii-code-146.html)

[Here's another one.](http://www.atwebresults.com/ascii-codes.php?type=2)